# K is compact and $f :K\to R$ continuous and $\forall x\in K$ exists$y \in K$ such that $f(y) \leq \frac{f(x)}{2}$ exists $p\in K$ such that $f(p) =0 $

Tags: real-analysis, continuity, compactness

if K is a compact set and $f : K \to  R$ a continuous function and suppose $\forall$  $x \in K$ exists $y \in K$ such that $f(y) \leq \frac{f(x)}{2}$ show that there exists a $p\in K$ such that $f(p) =0 $

I know the definitions of compact set and continuous function, but I can't think in a way to prove that there exists a $p\in K$ such that $f(p) =0 $ if the other conditions are satisfied. Can someone give me a hint?

Comment: $f(x)=-1$ for all $x$ gives  counter-example.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy $f(x) = -1 \ \forall \ x$ does not satisfy the given conditions at all. You can't find an $y$ such that $f(y) \leq -1/2$.

Comment: Take $y=x$. Isn't $-1 \leq -\frac 1 2 $.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy sorry, you're right

Comment: The correct hypothesis is likely to be $\forall x \in K, \exists y \in K, |f(y)| \leq \dfrac{1}{2}|f(x)|$. To solve this, use the fact that $|f|$ attains its minimum at a point $x_0$, and apply the hypothesis for $x=x_0$.